# How to create a frequency-dependent device with low losses at 50/60 Hz and high losses at 100 kHz

Tags: high-frequency, damping-factor, losses

I'm working on a device to dampen high-frequency transients. Here are the specifications:

- Rated current: 30 A RMS
- Losses at low frequency (50/60 Hz): <10 W (required steady-state condition)
- Losses at high frequency (>100 kHz): >2000 W (not steady-state, only fast transient)
- Size: <100 mm
- Materials available: copper, aluminum, low-carbon steel, stainless-steel

I tried several configuration with a cylindrical core (5 mm diameter) covered by some 'fins' with steel. It worked at some point, but didn't give me high enough losses at high frequencies (I checked it by simulation). Something like this below.

My plan was to have very high losses because when the frequency is high, the skin depth decreases and the current is forced to go forward and backward all the way in the surface of the fins. At lower frequencies, the current can be conducted in the aluminum core.

Conceptually, it worked, but the final behavior was not good enough.

[image]

I'm interested in new ideas or concepts that can be used for this objective. Other type of materials that are commonly used in industry could also be used.

Comment: Ferrite beads are used for this, but usually at higher frequencies.

Comment: Work out the equivalent impedance-frequency profile of what you want. For instance, at 100 kHz I can see the impedance will have around 2 ohm resistance. You need to fill in the gaps.

Comment: something that's smaller than 100mm in the longest direction and dissipates 2000W will inherently be a challenge to cool. This is a very potent tea kettle!

Comment: "Materials available: copper, aluminum, low-carbon steel, stainless-steel" Are you permitted to use one or more capacitors?

Comment: In fact, it will not operate in steady state condition at 100kHz. So the heat dissipation at this frequency is not of concern. I'll add this info into the question.

Answer (score 3):

We can solve for resistance by dividing power by current squared.  We have 11.1mΩ at LF, and 2.22Ω at HF.  This is a 200 ratio, and we need an equal frequency range to transition between these impedances; the impedance will be inductive in the transition band.  The equivalent circuit is:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJqsna.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

(inductor value as a placeholder for now)

In practice, the inductor probably has the R2 resistance in its wire, and R1 is wired in parallel with it.

We need the toe frequency somewhere above 60Hz, and the knee frequency somewhere below 100kHz.  This ratio is 1667, more than enough, so we can pick anywhere inbetween for the cutoffs.

Suppose we minimize the inductor value, keeping the knee close to but still comfortably away from 100kHz, say 50kHz.  We need \$L = \frac{R}{2 \pi F}\$ or 7µH.

The resulting toe frequency will be 200 times below or 250Hz.

We have an impedance curve like so:

[image]

Trying to construct a solid-metal implementation of this curve will be nontrivial.  The large inductance suggests, if not using magnetic loading, at least quite a long structure will be needed (on the order of 5m).  Most likely, a preferable solution will be using a parallel array of noninductive resistors, shunting an inductor wound on a Hi-Flux toroid of adequate size.

Incidentally, skin effect will not be a sufficient mechanism here, as that would give Z ~ sqrt(F) (when prepared in suitable fashion), too shallow to meet the frequency and impedance ratios requested; a lumped-equivalent circuit is required.

To get the overall size under 100mm, say as a bounding cube of same size, you will need water cooling.

Comment: wait, the way I interpret your schematic, this thing would shunt DC to ground and be practically no load to 100 kHz

Comment: It's a series element, driven by a current; the source and ground should be understood as the circuit it's embedded within. We're given no information about that unfortunately, but assuming the OP knows what they want, there exists a closed specification which can be filled in this way.

Comment: Well, this is fully aligned with I have found so far. Thank you very much for the good hints.

Comment: `In practice, the inductor probably has the R2 resistance in its wire, and R1 is wired in parallel with it.` It might turn out simpler if you imagine instead that L1 is one winding of a transformer and R1 is the load of the secondary (which can be a single turn, or even just a solid piece of metal). I.e. at 100 kHz, you do not require galvanic connection between the current carrying path amd the lossy material.

Answer (score 0):

Your specs are very similar to an induction cooktop. You might find it helpful to check how they work in detail.

What these use, is essentially a large inductor with copper wire and an extremely lossy core (the pot).

The dominant loss mechanism is eddy currents in the "core", which can be steel or aluminum. You select thr material based on the desired impedance at 100 kHz and the desired geometry. These imply a certain skin depth.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkeodB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

In practice, the contrast between low and high frequency will be even much larger, because R1 will be smaller at lower frequencies, due to larger skin depth.

Comment: Skin effect implies R ~ sqrt(F), and the model shown won't be representative; it's unlikely this method can provide a steep enough impedance curve. The "workpiece" could be made out of thin material however, avoiding skin effect in the range of interest; but foil would be harder to cool, and to fabricate.

Comment: @TimWilliams I think the actual impedance will be proportional to f^(3/2) in the transition band.. 1/2 from the skin effect of R1 and another 1 from the gradual appearance of coupling between the primary and the secondary. Look how the sim shows an exponent of 1 already while skin effect is not even included.

Comment: There's something deeper here: for a one-port (two-terminal general impedance element) to increase faster than f, or decrease faster than 1/f, it can only be by approaching a resonance (complex pole/zero pair); and then will have opposite slope past the peak. A pure R and L circuit can only increase at a rate f^alpha with 0 <= alpha <= 1 (or R and C, decrease at f^-alpha). Ultimately this comes down to Kramers-Kronig relations, which applies as the impedance function must be analytic.

Comment: @TimWilliams isn't it rather that the frequency dependence cannot change faster than a power of 1 without resonance? And here, it doesn't, the slope would go from 1/2 to 3/2, then back to 1/2

Comment: 3/2 is faster than 2/2?

Comment: Guess I either have to try it or read on the KK relationship for impedance spectroscopy @TimWilliams thanks for the pointers